# Tkinter Tooltip over a text only in a text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, hover, tooltip

***Description***:

I have a text widget which contains some text.
I want a tooltip over a word. Like, for a specific word, tooltip #1 and for other, tooltip #2, and so on.
When I tried to create one tooltip for a single word, it actually created a tooltip for the entire text widget. I know the reason because I passed the Text widget to the HoverInfo class.

---

***My Question:***

- How can I create a tooltip for a word in a text widget?
- And is it possible to define multiple tooltips dynamically for different words in a text widget?

---

My code for the ***Description***:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
import tkinter as tk

class HoverInfo(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, text, command=None):
       self._com = command
       Menu.__init__(self,parent, tearoff=0)
       if not isinstance(text, str):
          raise TypeError('Trying to initialise a Hover Menu with a non string type: ' + text.__class__.__name__)
       toktext=re.split('\n', text)
       for t in toktext:
          self.add_command(label = t)
          self._displayed=False
          self.master.bind("<Enter>",self.Display )
          self.master.bind("<Leave>",self.Remove )

    def __del__(self):
       self.master.unbind("<Enter>")
       self.master.unbind("<Leave>")

    def Display(self,event):
       if not self._displayed:
          self._displayed=True
          self.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
       if self._com != None:
          self.master.unbind_all("<Return>")
          self.master.bind_all("<Return>", self.Click)

    def Remove(self, event):
     if self._displayed:
       self._displayed=False
       self.unpost()
     if self._com != None:
       self.unbind_all("<Return>")

    def Click(self, event):
       self._com()



def HelloWorld():
    print('Hello World')


def vp_start_gui():
    global val, w, root, o
    root = Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=canvas.xview)
    canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    frame = tk.Frame(canvas) # frame does not get pack() as it needs to be embedded into canvas throught canvas.
    scroll.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
    frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda x: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))) # lambda function

    journal = tk.Text(frame, width = 75, height = 39)
    journal.configure(background="#f2f2f2")
    journal.configure(borderwidth="3")
    journal.configure(relief="groove")
    journal.grid() # grid instead
    journal.insert("end", "I want tooltip over this text only")    
    hover = HoverInfo(journal,'while hovering press return \n for an exciting msg', HelloWorld)


    root.mainloop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add tags to a span of characters in a text widget. You can then bind the mouse events `<Enter>` and `<Leave.` to those tags.

Here's a very contrived example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_info(text):
    label.configure(text=text)

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
label = tk.Label(root)

label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for color in ("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"):
    tag = color
    text = color
    text_widget.insert("end", text+"\n", (tag, ))

    text_widget.tag_configure(tag, background=color, foreground="white")
    text_widget.tag_bind(tag, "<Enter>",
                         lambda event, color=color: show_info(color))
    text_widget.tag_bind(tag, "<Leave>",
                         lambda event, color=color: show_info(""))

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you very much.
I would really appreciate if you could just provide an example of how to bind tags to the <Enter> and <Leave>.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you just explain this line? "text_widget.insert("end", text+"\n", (tag, ))" . What is the last argument "(tag, ))". Why is the second argument blank?

Comment: @RajMehta: it is a tuple.`(tag)` is not a tuple in python, it's an expression. `(tag,)` is a tuple.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried the code and could dynamically create tags and assign the label that I want for the individual word. But the function show_info is just configuring the label to show the text. How can I have it as a tooltip? I tried changing the label, but it throws "Tkinter exception error".

Comment: @RajMehta: I can't answer that in the comment section. You can do whatever you want in that function.

Comment: I tried creating a tooltip in that function. But it throws an error saying "str" object cannot be tk.
I understood the error. I cannot pass the string, it has to be a widget. But is it possible to create a toolkit for every tag? I have created a tag for every word, and I want to create a toolkit for a tag, is that possible or toolkit has to have a widget for its input?

Comment: @RajMehta: the smart thing is to create a single tooltip, and then just change the text on that tooltip as the mouse moves around. if you want, though, you can create one tooltip for each tag. There's no limitations either way.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could provide an example to create a tooltip on hovering over a text in a text widget.